# Spring Boot WebClient Request gives block terminated error

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, spring-data-rest, spring-webclient

I am making a call from a Vehicle service class containing a WebClient to a Price microservice for which I have used Spring Data Rest. I created a custom method to re-calculate a price for an id associated with a vehicle that has just been deleted. The reason for creating a new price is that when a vehicle is added to that vacant id, the price already calculated is assigned to the vehicle just added. When I ran my application, I am getting "block terminated with an error". The affected code and stacktrace is shown below. I will really appreciate helping in resolving this error and getting the code to work. Let me know if you need further clarification or sections of my code to be added.

CarService.java (VehicleApplication)

```
    public void delete(Long id) {
        /**
         * TODO: Find the car by ID from the `repository` if it exists.
         *   If it does not exist, throw a CarNotFoundException
         */

        Optional<Car> optionalCar = repository.findById(id);
        Car car = optionalCar.orElseThrow(CarNotFoundException::new);

        /**
         * TODO: Delete the car from the repository.
         */

        repository.delete(car);
        String newPrice = priceClient.createPrice(id);
        System.out.println("NEW PRICE " + newPrice );
    }
```

PriceClient.java (VehicleApplication)

```
    public String createPrice(Long vehicleId) {
        try {
            Price price = client
                    .get()
                    .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                            .path("services/price/generatePrice/replacementPrice/")
                            .queryParam("vehicleId", vehicleId)
                            .build()
                    )
                    .retrieve().bodyToMono(Price.class).block();

            System.out.println("PRICECLIENT "+ price.getCurrency());

            return String.format("%s %s", price.getCurrency(), price.getPrice());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Unexpected error retrieving price for vehicle {}", vehicleId, e);
        }
        return "(consult price)";
    }
```

PriceRepository.java (PriceServiceApplication)

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "price", path = "price")
public interface PriceRepository extends CrudRepository<Price, Long>, PriceRepositoryCustom {

    Price findPriceByVehicleId(@Param("vehicleId") Long vehicleId);

}
```

PriceRepositoryImpl.java (PriceServiceApplication)

```
@BasePathAwareController
@RequestMapping("/generatePrice")
public class PriceRepositoryImpl{

    @GetMapping("/replacementPrice")
    public Price newPriceForVehicileId(@RequestParam Long vehicleId) {

        return new Price("USD", randomPrice(), vehicleId);

    }

    public static BigDecimal randomPrice() {
        return new BigDecimal(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(1, 5))
                .multiply(new BigDecimal(5000d)).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    }
}
```

application.properties (PriceServiceApplication)

```
server.port=8082


#configure base path for rest apis
#spring.data.rest.base-path=/api/v1/services
spring.data.rest.base-path=/services


#h2
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:pricedata

spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

#Eureka
spring.application.name=pricing-service

eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
eureka.client.service-url.default-zone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
instance.preferIpAddress=true

eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true

eureka.client.enabled=true
spring.cloud.config.enabled=false
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost

spring.cloud.loadbalancer.ribbon.enable=false

#Actuator
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.info.env.enabled=true
info.app.name= Pricing Service
info.app.description= Price Generation for Vehicle Microservice
info.app.version=1.0.0
```

Resulting Error

```
2023-05-23 20:32:52.370 ERROR 10020 --- [io-8080-exec-10] c.u.vehicles.client.prices.PriceClient   : Unexpected error retrieving price for vehicle 1

org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$NotFound: 404 Not Found
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException.create(WebClientResponseException.java:180) ~[spring-webflux-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultResponseSpec.lambda$createResponseException$13(DefaultWebClient.java:495) ~[spring-webflux-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:107) ~[reactor-core-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:345) ~[reactor-core-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1510) ~[reactor-core-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:100) ~[reactor-core-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onComplete(FluxOnAssembly.java:355) ~[reactor-core-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapFuseable.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onComplete(FluxContextStart.java:122) ~[reactor-core-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onComplete(FluxOnAssembly.java:355) ~[reactor-core-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapFuseable.java:336) ~[reactor-core-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onComplete(FluxOnAssembly.java:355) ~[reactor-core-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilterFuseable.java:385) ~[reactor-core-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onComplete(FluxOnAssembly.java:355) ~[reactor-core-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1511) ~[reactor-core-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollectList$MonoCollectListSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollectList.java:121) ~[reactor-core-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onComplete(FluxOnAssembly.java:355) ~[reactor-core-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapFuseable.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onComplete(FluxOnAssembly.java:355) ~[reactor-core-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeekFuseable.java:271) ~[reactor-core-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onComplete(FluxOnAssembly.java:355) ~[reactor-core-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:252) ~[reactor-core-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onComplete(FluxOnAssembly.java:355) ~[reactor-core-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:136) ~[reactor-core-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.terminateReceiver(FluxReceive.java:390) ~[reactor-netty-0.8.8.RELEASE.jar:0.8.8.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:197) ~[reactor-netty-0.8.8.RELEASE.jar:0.8.8.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:338) ~[reactor-netty-0.8.8.RELEASE.jar:0.8.8.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:350) ~[reactor-netty-0.8.8.RELEASE.jar:0.8.8.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.terminate(ChannelOperations.java:399) ~[reactor-netty-0.8.8.RELEASE.jar:0.8.8.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:555) ~[reactor-netty-0.8.8.RELEASE.jar:0.8.8.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:91) ~[reactor-netty-0.8.8.RELEASE.jar:0.8.8.RELEASE]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) ~[netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) ~[netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352) ~[netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102) ~[netty-codec-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) ~[netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) ~[netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352) ~[netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:438) ~[netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:323) ~[netty-codec-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:297) ~[netty-codec-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:253) ~[netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) ~[netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) ~[netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352) ~[netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1408) ~[netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) ~[netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) ~[netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:930) ~[netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163) ~[netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:682) ~[netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:617) ~[netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:534) ~[netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496) ~[netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:906) ~[netty-common-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Assembly trace from producer [reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap] :
    reactor.core.publisher.Mono.flatMap(Mono.java:2490)
    org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultResponseSpec.lambda$null$1(DefaultWebClient.java:430)
Error has been observed by the following operator(s):
    |_  Mono.flatMap ⇢ org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultResponseSpec.lambda$null$1(DefaultWebClient.java:430)
    |_  Mono.flatMap ⇢ org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultResponseSpec.bodyToMono(DefaultWebClient.java:429)

    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:93) ~[reactor-core-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1494) ~[reactor-core-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
        at com.udacity.vehicles.client.prices.PriceClient.createPrice(PriceClient.java:89) ~[classes/:na]
        at com.udacity.vehicles.service.CarService.delete(CarService.java:156) ~[classes/:na]
        at com.udacity.vehicles.api.CarController.delete(CarController.java:126) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doDelete(FrameworkServlet.java:930) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:666) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:836) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1747) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        ... 1 common frames omitted

NEW PRICE (consult price)
```

Comment: According your settings the result endpoint will be: `services/generatePrice/replacementPrice`

Answer (score 2):

The actual error is a 404, as indicated in the log file:

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$NotFound: 404 Not Found
```

It means that your URL is not constructed correctly:

```java
uriBuilder
    .path("services/price/generatePrice/replacementPrice/")
    .queryParam("vehicleId", vehicleId)
    .build()
```

I can only guess here, but maybe the last `/` should not be there?

Comment: I implemented the suggested change, that is removing the last ```/``` , but got the same 404 error.

Comment: @Othello What is the full URL supposed to be? Did you test it (with either curl, Postman, directly from a browser...)?

Comment: The full URL is supposed to be ```http://localhost:8082/services/price/generatePrice/replacementPrice?vehicleId=1```. tested this URL using Postman but I got 404 error.

Comment: Hi @Othello, I have added my answer, please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with the path you're using. From what I can see, it should either be `/generatePrice/replacementPrice` or `/services/generatePrice/replacementPrice` I'm not sure where the `/price/` part of the url came from.

I suppose the correct url is `/services/generatePrice/replacementPrice` since you have `spring.data.rest.base-path=/services` but it might be worth it to try both tbh.

update your call like so:

```
uriBuilder
    .path("services/generatePrice/replacementPrice")
    .queryParam("vehicleId", vehicleId)
    .build()
```

or test this url: `http://localhost:8082/services/generatePrice/replacementPrice?vehicleId=1` in postman

Answer (score 1):

Endpoint generated from `@RepositoryRestResource` is different than those generated from `BasePathAwareController` as per https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.overriding-sdr-response-handlers.annotations.

If you use `@RepositoryRestResource`, endpoints will get generated automatically. For `BasePathAwareController`, you can define custom endpoints.
In addition to that, you have defined `spring.data.rest.base-path=/services`
meaning it will add base path for your all default endpoints & custom endpoints.

So if you use  `http://localhost:8082/services/` you will get some JSON response back which looks like :

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "price" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8082/services/price{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8082/services/profile"
    }
  }
}
```

RepositoryRestResource automatically created `services/price` endpoint for you.

You are using `BasePathAwareController` to access `/replacementPrice` service, and here you don't need to use `/price` which is part of @RepositoryRestResource.

So to access `generatePrice/replacementPrice/` I am suggesting you to just use `services/generatePrice/replacementPrice/` & that will fetch details from `newPriceForVehicileId` method.

If you want to use `price` endpoint, I am suggesting to use it separately, something like,  `services/price` without use of custom endpoint created by BasePathAwareController.